# Full screen background-image influences div size and other content

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

I have the following problem: I have a full screen image slider one my website which is responsive. The image size always adapts on the window size. My solution is as follows:

```
.picture {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
}

<div class="owl-carousel slides">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="picture" style="background-image: url('myURL')"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that you can see the other content of the page at the sliders position when loading the page. The reason is that the picture container has no width when the page is loading. The width is calculated based on the image width. For a better understanding: I am loading the page, then for a short moment I can see the div content at the top and then the slider is loaded and the content is below the slider where it should be.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `.slides { clear:both; }`

Comment: have you tried wrapping you JS with `document.ready(function(){});`

Comment: @TamilSelvan .slides { clear:both; } doesn't target the problem, thanks anyway!

Comment: @JoshSpears yes, all my code is wrapped in document.ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the CSS3 Viewport Unit.

```
.picture {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh) is okay, except IE.